# bundler: command not found: unicorn_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gitlab

While restarting gitlab I get this:

```
Starting both the GitLab Unicorn and Sidekiqbundler: command not found: unicorn_rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install
```

I installed gitlab 6.3.0 with ruby 1.9.3 on my centos 6.3 vm.

I tried this from user 'git':

> bundle install --without development test pgsql --no-deployment

And I get this:

> Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:

Which is asking for sudo privileges.
It then does for many packages (gems) and fails.

```
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT 1:

When I manually try to install **any** gem (as user 'git') I get this: (here trying with bundler)

> gem install bundler ERROR:  While executing gem ...
>   (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448 directory.

An **ls -l** of the directory gives me:

```
[git@jpvip gitlab]$ ls -la /usr/local/rvm/gems
total 16
drwxrwsr-x  4 root rvm 4096 Nov 21 17:29 .
drwxrwsr-x 24 root rvm 4096 Nov 21 17:21 ..
drwxrwsr-x  2 root rvm 4096 Nov 21 17:29 cache
drwxrwsr-x  8 root rvm 4096 Nov 21 17:29 ruby-1.9.3-p448
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root rvm   57 Nov 21 17:29 ruby-1.9.3-p448@global -> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

Also I checked user 'git' was not a member of rvm. So is this the issue? I never changed file/folder ownership or the group file for that matter.

Comment: What's the complete error message when you try to install the gem via `gem install i18n -v '0.6.5'` ?

Comment: Updated the question. I can now run gitlab by installing everything as root, but that is rather icky.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar error `bundler: command not found: unicorn_rails` after migration from Gitlab 5.4 to 6.0.

The problem was due to cached by bundler value of `--without` from previous Gitlab version:

```
root@2e7cc95677d2:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
...

without
Set for your local app (/home/git/gitlab/.bundle/config): "development:test:mysql:unicorn:aws"

...
```

I removed it with

```
root@2e7cc95677d2:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle config --delete without`
```

and performed `bundle install` again (note that this string is for PostgreSQL configuration):

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --without development test mysql --deployment
```